# Check if a value is withing a list of ranges in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists of ranges here:

I am trying to check if a value within any ranges of one of the ranges and if yest, return the index. Is there any way to check this without having to do a list comprehension?

```
>>> a=range(1,4)
>>> b=range(4,7)
>>> c=range(7,10)
>>> d=[a,b,c]
>>> d
[range(1, 4), range(4, 7), range(7, 10)]
>>> 3 in d[0]
True
```

Comment: `any(var in subrange for subrange in d)` for general check. As for index, you would need to loop over those.

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  `d=list(a)+list(b)+list(c)` combines them all into one list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_range_ind(num, min_val, max_val):
    if num in range(min_val, max_val+1):
        return num - min_val + 1

get_range_ind(6, 3, 9)

>>> 4
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. When answering questions it is always helpful to provide at least a bit of commentary on your code ie why did you make the choices you made? Fir example 'In my solution I generate a list of all integers from `min_val` to `max_val` inclusive using the `range` function and check if the number is in the list,, this is more performant than xxx because yyy`